# Rotational dynamics regarding uniform rod

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

Is centripetal force present in rotating objects? I just solved a question in which an uniform rod rotates about a vertical axis with its one end pivoted. The angular acceleration is found by just equating the torque due to mass of the rod with I alpha. Why is centripetal force and torque due to it not considered when every circular motion has centripetal acceleration. If i have wrongly understood some concept pls correct me.

Comment: What is a vertical point?

Comment: I meant vertical axis.. Sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centripetal force does act on every particle in the rotating rod.

However the centripetal force is directed towards the centre from that point.

Therefore the torque caused by it would be $0$ as torque is $rF \sin \theta$  and for this $\theta = 0$